# Simple GCP cloud function gives Error ID: 945b0f01

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am following:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-functions-python-http#2
to deploy cloud function in GCP.

After I execute `gcloud functions deploy` I get this error:

```
Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)...⠹                                                                
For Cloud Build Stackdriver Logs, visit: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=XXXXXXXX&advancedFilter=resource.type%3Dbuild%0Aresource.labels.build_id%3Dd01ddb18-ca8f-4157-9538-faf11b530aa2%0AlogName%3Dprojects%2FXXXXXXXXX%2Flogs%2Fcloudbuild
Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)...failed.                                                          
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed: found incompatible dependencies: "functions-framework 2.1.2 has requirement click<8.0,>=7.0, but you have click 8.0.0."; Error ID: 945b0f01
```

I googled this error but not much comes back.

Comment: Are you following the tutorial step by step? I just tried deploying the same function from the tutorial and it deployed just fine.

Comment: Read the error message `functions-framework 2.1.2 has requirement click<8.0,>=7.0, but you have click 8.0.0.` Create/modify the requirements.txt and specify a supported version.

Comment: What's your requirements? It's a dependency version conflict. Try to update them.

Comment: I agree with the comments above, it'd be nice to see the requirements.txt file you're using for the deployment of the function to see if you're approaching this correctly. Please see the [official documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-python) for more insight on how to use external dependencies on Google Cloud Functions.